# How to access MySQL server with user password issued through LibreOffice Base frontend?

Tags: 12.04, password, libreoffice, mysql, database

When dist-upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 UpdateManager asked to enter a "new" user password for MySQL. I denied 3 times. This asking was put misleadingly. I better should have entered a user password for me for the »MyQSL« privilege system, as I know now.

Now my database »mysql« > table »user« does not shows a password entry for me. I can do most administrative tasks on my MySQL database though. I feel that this is a security gap.
I'd like closing it.

I entered a password. But now I cannot access my MySQL server through my LibreOffice Base frontend any more: "Access denied."
How to rconcile both requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This is rather ambiguous, you need to provide more detail:

1) The new password that the system asked you about: Which application asked you for it? was that MySQL server or was it Base?
2) "I denied 3 times" does that mean you entered it wrong multiple times?
3) "Now my database »mysql« > table »user« does not shows a password entry for me". Does that mean that:

```
SELECT Password FROM mysql.user;
```

returns empty for your user. Is that the root user?

4) You seem to be able to connect in some other way that is not using Base. What is that?

I will answer wabout what I did as I had a similar problem:

First, users updating Ubuntu and using Base should make sure Java classpath is stored correctly, if not try:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

Then, my second issue was that the MySQL user actually dissapeared. For this I just created it again using phpmyadmin. **Restarted** sql and run Base. Note that Base remembered the user I previously had.

Comment: quinestor wrote: